# Counting unique values within a time window

Tags: python, sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have data that looks like (over 100.000 rows):

```
timestamp               Location person
2017-09-04 08:07:00 UTC A        x
2017-09-04 08:08:00 UTC B        y
2017-09-04 08:09:00 UTC A        y
2017-09-04 08:07:00 UTC A        x
2017-09-04 08:27:00 UTC B        x
```

What I would like:

```
Location  Nr_of_persons_working_at_the_same_time
A         2
B         1
```

Explanation

```
timestamp               Location person
2017-09-04 08:07:00 UTC A        x       <--- first action in A by person x
2017-09-04 08:08:00 UTC B        y       <--- different first action in B by person y
2017-09-04 08:09:00 UTC A        y       <--- second action in A, but could be different action as person x might be gone
2017-09-04 08:07:00 UTC A        x       <--- person x is still there, so count of persons in A is 2
2017-09-04 08:27:00 UTC B        x       <--- not a different action, person x coming in after 20 minutes, count of persons working at the same time remains 1
```

CONTEXT

I want to find out how many people (person) are working in the same location (Location) by looking at a time window (timestamp) of max 10 minutes and checking whether a person is really working simultaneously or just taking over their shift within that frame. I get the data with a SQL query and could parse it using either SQL or Python. SQL is preferred.

TRIED SOLUTIONS

- Grouping by location, timestamp leads to 'hard cuts'
- Probably need an so-called window function. But after sorting on timestamp, how do I prevent Locations mixing up?

Note:
If easier, I can also try to do this in Python, but I rather not given the size of the dataset and my limited options to do it in the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
with mytable as (
select cast('2017-09-04 08:07:00' as datetime) as _timestamp ,'A' as Location,'x' as person union all
select cast('2017-09-04 08:08:00' as datetime) as _timestamp ,'B' as Location,'y' as person union all
select cast('2017-09-04 08:09:00' as datetime) as _timestamp ,'A' as Location,'y' as person union all
select cast('2017-09-04 08:07:00' as datetime) as _timestamp ,'A' as Location,'x' as person union all
select cast('2017-09-04 08:27:00' as datetime) as _timestamp ,'B' as Location,'x' as person 
),
sorted_entry
as (
select  *,
        ifnull(first_value(_timestamp) over(partition by Location  order by _timestamp ),_timestamp ) as prev_timestamp ,
        ifnull(lag(person) over(partition by Location  order by _timestamp ),person ) as another_person
        
from mytable 
)
,flagged 
as 
(
select *,
        case when person <> another_person then (
            case when datetime_diff(_timestamp,prev_timestamp,minute) <= 10 then 1
            else 0 end
        )
        else 0
        end as flag
from sorted_entry 
)
select location ,sum(flag) + 1 as _count
from flagged
group by location
```